# Ios push-notification PHP script not working for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ios, ubuntu

I'm working on an iOS app that use iOS Push Notifications. I want to send the notification from a php script on my windows PC. I use this php script to send notification and it works well too:

```
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'sdsdsdsdsczc2';
$sound = '';
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'awertf';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'badge' => +1,
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => $sound

    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

This php script works well on **windows** but now i'm working on **Ubuntu 14.04** operating system and same php script is giving me error.

```
 Message:  stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I guess it's something related with port 2195. But how to solve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an enormously helpful link to find:

http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php
http://php.net/manual/en/context.php

An official document describing the changes made to openssl in PHP 5.6
It's usefull to learn one more parameter that Tou should have set to false/true:   for example "verify_peer_name"=>false

So some code looks like this:

```
<?php
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  

$response = file_get_contents('ssl://'.$host.':'.$port, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));

echo $response; ?>
```